# How can I change the header of WordPress 'retrieve_password' email?

Tags: php, wordpress, email-headers

I noticed WordPress give us some filters to customize the password reset request email like `wp_mail_from`, `retrieve_password_title` and `retrieve_password_message` and these last two are executed in the `retrieve_password` function at `wp-login.php` as following:

```
$title = apply_filters( 'retrieve_password_title', $title );
$message = apply_filters( 'retrieve_password_message', $message, $key );

if ( $message && !wp_mail( $user_email, wp_specialchars_decode( $title ), $message ) )
    wp_die( __('The e-mail could not be sent.') . "<br />\n" . __('Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.') );

return true;
```

That's cool but I also realized the `wp_mail` function does not use any header which make me believe everything should be override with filters.

Is there a filter to override the headers? Specifically `Content-Type`? And where would be the best place to register them?

Comment: I found the filter `'wp_mail_content_type` but I'm not sure where would be the best place to register it. Inside the message filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run the filter `wp_mail_content_type` only in `wp-login.php` page, we can use [one of its action hooks](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-login.php#L435). Untested:

```
add_action( 'login_form_retrievepassword', function()
{
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function( $old_content_type )
    {
        $new_content_type = 'text/plain';
        return $new_content_type;
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't want to change all my content types since I have different mail senders and different templates (plain text and html).

Comment: (off-topic), please check the rejection reason: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4913168

Comment: please check the WordPress coding standards: http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#brace-style

Comment: Stack or not Stack, if a framework has a code convention/standard it should be followed the same way any "nice behaviour practices" should be. For example not changing someone's else code. In this case should we follow the WP standards or keep your "bad styled" code just because  "we don't change other people's style". Is it ok to write my code inline and minified than?

Comment: Let's get philosophical ;) I follow pretty much all WP standards **but** my curly braces position.

Comment: IF I WRITE A QUESTION AND MY CODE IN UPPERCASE BECAUSE IT'S EASIER TO READ WILL I BE ABLE TO DENY ANY REVISIONS JUST BECAUSE HERE IN STACK OVERFLOW WE DON'T CHANGE THE OTHER PEOPLE'S STYLE?

Comment: For potato sake, man, things are getting out of hand. **Just don't touch other people's *code***, everything else is fair game as long as you're improving ***text*** clarity and comprehension. Passar bem.